# casting system.array object to int[] string or other type's objects

Tags: c#, system.array

I am learning c# and trying to understand the "type oriented" aspects of it.

So the other day I needed to receive an System.Array object from a method.
Then I tried to work with it's individual objects, so i tried to address it with an index.
Compiler wouldn't let me, saying that System.Array object do not support indexing.

But isn't Array is the base class to all arrays ([System.Array on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx))? How is that int[] supports indexing and Array[] doesn't?

here is some code to demonstrate the problem:

```
int[] intArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int t;
Array sysArray;       
Console.WriteLine("{0}", intArray.GetType().ToString()); // output: System.Int32[]
sysArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 10);
Console.WriteLine("{0}", sysArray.GetType().ToString()); // output: System.Int32[]
sysArray = intArray; //compiles ok
//t = sysArray[4]; This line produces error Error 2 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an
// expression of type 'System.Array'
//t = intArray[4]; This line compiles ok
```

So what we have here is 2 objects, that seem to be of the same type. 
But one is implementing indexing and the other is not, how is it possible?

---

a reference to the replies

after reading your comments i think i got the sense of things.
int[] is and array of objects. each of the objects is a struct of type int32.
Array[] is an array of objects. each of the objects is a class of type Array.
meaning : an array of arrays.
as i can display in the following code:

```
Array[] sysArrayOfArray = new Array[SIZE_OF_THE_MOTHER_ARRAY];
sysArrayOfArray[0] = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int),SIZE_OF_FIRST_CHILD_ARRAY);
sysArrayOfArray[1] = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int),SIZE_OF_FIRST_SECOND_ARRAY);
```

and so on...
so I understood why the way i tried to access the elements of sysArray was wrong.
intArray -> 1 array of many ints
sysArray -> 1 class (which grants access to many ints)

from the language's point of view sysArray is not an Array at all, it is only a reference to 1 object (of type System.Array)

(sorry for repeating a bit, but it really helps set things in my head)

thank you all for guiding in understanding that difference.

regarding the solutions.. that what i was looking for and worked for me best:

```
 Array sysArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int),3);
 int[] intArray = new int[3];
 int one, ten, hundred;
 sysArray.SetValue(1, 0);
 sysArray.SetValue(10,1);
 sysArray.SetValue(100,2);
 intArray = (int[])sysArray;// works, but forces me to create a new reference
 one = ((int[])sysArray)[0];// works and is exactly what i was looking for...
 ten = ((int[])sysArray)[1];
 hundred = ((int[])sysArray)[2];
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  An int is an object....So what you are doing makes little sense.

Comment: Good question. Shows that System.Array is not just an Array after all....Where is this world going MS?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Casting will take care of the difference:

```
    t = (sysArray as int[])[4];
```

You are seeing that both arrays are of type `System.Int32[]`, because they are (which is why this cast works).

Answer (score 5):

`int` is declared as a `struct` in the `BCL`

```
public struct Int32 : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, IComparable<Int32>, Equatable<Int32>
```

Whilst `Array` is declared like so:

```
public abstract class Array : ICloneable, IList, IStructuralComparable, IStructuralEquatable
```

So they are not actually the same.

If you do want to get items from Array using an indexer, I think you will need to do this:

```
int number = ((IList<int>)sysArray)[4];
```

The reason is due to how the indexer method is declared in Array:

```
Object IList.this[int index] { 
  get { return GetValue(index); }
  set { SetValue(value, index); } 
}
```

Since `IList` is declared in the signature, it means that you will need to cast `sysArray` into a `IList<int>` in order to access the indexer. If, instead, the indexer had been declared like this:

```
Object this[int index] {
```

then yes, you could do `sysArray[0];` without any problems.

Comment: Again, the OP is not asking why a single `int` can't be indexed. They are asking why a generic `System.Array` object can't be indexed.

Comment: When using `int[]` you're actually using a C# language construct i.e. arrays. That means there is in-built support for index accessing e.g. `myarray[23];`. In essence, your accessing an array of `structs` (int) The class `Array` is an object in itself, and so when using index access on it, you're not using the C# language, rather you're using whatever the indexer method is on that class i.e. `Object IList.this[int index]`. So in a nutshell, the index accessor methods for each type is totally different.

Comment: I do not think arrays are a "C# language construct". Using square brackets for array element indexing is a language construct...the existence of arrays is a fundamental feature of the CLI. See **ECMA-335:8.9.1 Array types**. As for IList, it includes (as you note) the indexer `this[int index]`. So how can System.Array implement IList without implementing the required member `this[int index]`?

Comment: Hmmm, I can see where you're going with this. The issue is that `Array` has it's indexer implement via `Object IList.this[int index]`. If it was declared `Object this[int index]` then you could do `sysArray[0]` without any problems. But because `IList` is declared in the signature, that makes a difference, and causes us to have to cast `sysArray` in order to access it's indexer. I think the ultimate question is why bother with the `Array` class at all?

Comment: thank you both, your example and discussion actually helped me understand what sysArray really was. @JasonEvans

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at the interfaces that each object implements. `Array` implements `System.Collections.IList` which provides an object indexer while `int` does not supply an `IList` implementation.

Comment: That's not what the OP is implying. The OP is asking why the abstract System.Array class does not allow element access using indexer syntax: It's the expression `sysarray[4]` that bombs.

Answer (score 1):

System.Array is an abstract base class.  The microsoft documentation says it all...

```
Provides methods for creating, manipulating, searching, and sorting arrays, thereby
serving as the base class for all arrays in the common language runtime.
```

System.Array does not provide an implementation for the indexer.

What will work for you is this...

```
int[] sysArray = (int[])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `eventTypes` are objects containing integer values (`object[] eventTypes`):

```
int[] eventTypeIDs = eventTypes.Select(Convert.ToInt32).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read values of Array by using the GetValue function.

```
array.GetValue(1);
array.GetValue(1,2);
```